# I can click buttons even when the isClickable property set to false

Tags: android, kotlin

## Activity Code

Here, enableOrDisable(), I am calling if myValue = 2, and I have sent the 2 value in the intent of the previous activity but still, I am able to click the buttons, please send some solution how to do it or what is wrong I am doing? Help would be greatly appreciated. and I am trying to do like if myValue is other than 2 then my buttons will all be clickable but as soon as the player with myValue 1 clicks it gets registered in firebase and be listened by both the players and after listening the player who clicked changes all the remaining unclicked button to false and the player who listens, that Player button becomes clickable but I don't know why both players can click at the same time.

```
class OnlineGame : AppCompatActivity() {
private var player1Record = 0
private var player2Record = 0
private var myValue:Int ?= null
private lateinit var scoreCard: TextView
private var myClicks = ArrayList<Int>()
private var choices = arrayListOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
private var count = 0
private val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://tictactoe8088-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app")
private val myRef = database.reference
private var sessionId:String ?= null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    sessionId = intent.getStringExtra("sessionId").toString()
    myValue = intent.getIntExtra("playerValue",10)
    if(myValue == 2)
        enableOrDisable(false)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_online_game)
    listenToChangeColors()
}

private fun enableOrDisable(trueOrfalse: Boolean){
    Log.d(TAG, "enableOrDisable: myValue = 2")
    for(i in choices){
        when(i){
            1 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)?.isEnabled = trueOrfalse
            2 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)?.isEnabled = trueOrfalse
            3 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)?.isEnabled = trueOrfalse
            4 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)?.isEnabled = trueOrfalse
            5 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button5)?.isEnabled = trueOrfalse
            6 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button6)?.isEnabled = trueOrfalse
            7 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button7)?.isEnabled = trueOrfalse
            8 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button8)?.isEnabled = trueOrfalse
            9 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button9)?.isEnabled = trueOrfalse
        }
    }
}

private fun listenToChangeColors() {
    var whoClicked:Int ?=  null
    myRef.child("Users").child("GameSessions").child(sessionId.toString()).child("ButtonClicked")
        .addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val td = snapshot.value.toString().toInt()  /* td = buttonClicked*/
                if(td.equals(1..9)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: condition is true")
                    when(td){
                        1 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)?.isClickable = false
                        2 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)?.isClickable = false
                        3 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)?.isClickable = false
                        4 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)?.isClickable = false
                        5 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button5)?.isClickable = false
                        6 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button6)?.isClickable = false
                        7 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button7)?.isClickable = false
                        8 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button8)?.isClickable = false
                        9 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button9)?.isClickable = false
                    }
                    choices.remove(td)
                    drawOnButton(td)
                }
            }
            private fun drawOnButton(buttonValue: Int) {
                myRef.child("Users").child("GameSessions").child(sessionId.toString()).child("whichPlayer")
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object:ValueEventListener{
                        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                            whoClicked = snapshot.value.toString().toInt()
                        }
                        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                            TODO("Not yet implemented")
                        }
                    })
                when(buttonValue){
                    1 -> draw(findViewById(R.id.button1),whoClicked)
                    2 -> draw(findViewById(R.id.button2),whoClicked)
                    3 -> draw(findViewById(R.id.button3),whoClicked)
                    4 -> draw(findViewById(R.id.button4),whoClicked)
                    5 -> draw(findViewById(R.id.button5),whoClicked)
                    6 -> draw(findViewById(R.id.button6),whoClicked)
                    7 -> draw(findViewById(R.id.button7),whoClicked)
                    8 -> draw(findViewById(R.id.button8),whoClicked)
                    9 -> draw(findViewById(R.id.button9),whoClicked)
                }
                if(whoClicked != myValue)
                    enableOrDisable(true)
                else
                    enableOrDisable(false)
                if(myValue == 1)
                {
                    myRef.child("Users").child("GameSessions").child(sessionId.toString()).child("whichPlayer").setValue(2)
                }
                else{
                    myRef.child("Users").child("GameSessions").child(sessionId.toString()).child("whichPlayer").setValue(1)
                }
            }

            private fun draw(buttonToDraw: Button?, whoClicked: Int?) {
                if(whoClicked == 1){
                    buttonToDraw?.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.player1Color))
                    buttonToDraw?.text = "X"
                }
                else{
                    buttonToDraw?.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.player2Color))
                    buttonToDraw?.text = "O"
                }
                return
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
}

fun buttonClicked(view: View) {
    val whichButton = view as Button
    var buttonId = 0
    when (whichButton.id) {
        R.id.button1 -> buttonId = 1
        R.id.button2 -> buttonId = 2
        R.id.button3 -> buttonId = 3
        R.id.button4 -> buttonId = 4
        R.id.button5 -> buttonId = 5
        R.id.button6 -> buttonId = 6
        R.id.button7 -> buttonId = 7
        R.id.button8 -> buttonId = 8
        R.id.button9 -> buttonId = 9
    }
    myRef.child("Users").child("GameSessions").child(sessionId.toString()).child("ButtonClicked").setValue(buttonId)
    myRef.child("Users").child("GameSessions").child(sessionId.toString()).child("whichPlayer").setValue(myValue)
    myClicks.add(buttonId)
    checkWin()
    count += 1
}

private fun checkWin() {
    val result = calculateWin(myClicks)
    if ( result == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 Won", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        player1Record += 1
        restart()
    }

}
private fun calculateWin( clicks : ArrayList<Int>) : Int {
    if (clicks.contains(1) && clicks.contains(2) && clicks.contains(3))
        return 1
    else if (clicks.contains(4) && clicks.contains(5) && clicks.contains(6))
        return 1
    else if (clicks.contains(7) && clicks.contains(8) && clicks.contains(9))
        return 1
    else if (clicks.contains(1) && clicks.contains(4) && clicks.contains(7))
        return 1
    else if (clicks.contains(2) && clicks.contains(5) && clicks.contains(8))
        return 1
    else if (clicks.contains(3) && clicks.contains(6) && clicks.contains(9))
        return 1
    else if (clicks.contains(1) && clicks.contains(5) && clicks.contains(9))
        return 1
    else if (clicks.contains(3) && clicks.contains(5) && clicks.contains(7))
        return 1
    else if (count == 9) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Draw", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        restart()
        return 2
    }
    return 0
}

private fun restart() {
    TODO("Not Properly Implemented yet")
    var clearAllButton: Button?
    myClicks.clear()
    myClicks.clear()
    for (i in 1..9) {
        clearAllButton = when (i) {
            1 -> findViewById(R.id.button1)
            2 -> findViewById(R.id.button2)
            3 -> findViewById(R.id.button3)
            4 -> findViewById(R.id.button4)
            5 -> findViewById(R.id.button5)
            6 -> findViewById(R.id.button6)
            7 -> findViewById(R.id.button7)
            8 -> findViewById(R.id.button8)
            9 -> findViewById(R.id.button9)
            else -> null
        }
        clearAllButton!!.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.teal_200,null))
        clearAllButton.text = ""
        clearAllButton.isClickable = true
        count = 0
    }
    scoreCard = findViewById(R.id.win_records)
    scoreCard.text = "Player 1 : $player1Record\nPlayer 2 : $player2Record"
}
```

}

## Layout Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id= "@+id/table_layout"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".OnlineGame">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5pt"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5pt"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5pt"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5pt"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5pt"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5pt"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5pt"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5pt"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5pt"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/win_records"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/win_records" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: please don't add your code as images, rather add it as text

Comment: Use isEnabled instead of isClickable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: guys i edited the post please give it a read one more time please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was doing it above the setContentView()

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_online_game)
listenToChangeColors()
if(myValue == 2)
    enableOrDisable(false)
```

do it like this and everything will be fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `setEnabled` propeties

Code be like

```
button1.setEnabled = false
button1.isClickable = false
```

Comment: that also not working

Comment: can you please read my question again I edited and gave a proper explanation of what I am trying to achieve and what is happening :"(

Answer (score -1):

You maybe should use "setEnabled" instead of isClickable ?

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer?

Comment: An answer to Giriraj Singh's issue, whence my answer.

Comment: not working my friend

Comment: can you please read y question again I edited it more and given full code